# phantom images after going from split screen to full screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, vulkan

I am writing a game for Android using the NDK.  My game uses vulkan if it is available and otherwise uses OpenGL.

I have a problem where if you put the game in split screen mode with the device held in portrait orientation, then resize the game to full screen mode, an after image of the game on the old view is still visible.  Note: doing this with the game triggers SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceDestroyed (in Java) to be called, which in turn shuts down my render thread in C++.  My callback for surfaceDestroyed tells the C++ render thread to stop, then joins it.

I can fix this in OpenGL by calling glClearColor with any color, then calling eglSwapBuffers right before the render thread shuts down.

Is this a valid fix for OpenGL?  Is there something else I should be doing to clean out the old surface?  I
verified that ANativeWindow_release is called on the window I get from ANativeWindow_fromSurface before I exit the render thread.

Then I tried to do the same thing in vulkan and ran into problems again... I used vkCmdClearColorImage by do
ing the following:

(1) vkQueueWaitIdle(presentQueue)

(2) vkAquireNextImageKHR

(3) initialize the corresponding command buffer with:

(3a) ImageMemoryBarrier VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED -> VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, 0 -> VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT

(3b) vkCmdClearColor VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL

(3c) ImageMemoryBarrier VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL -> VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR, VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT -> VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT

(4) vkQueueSubmit(graphicsQueue...)

(5) vkQueuePresentKHR(presentQueue...)

(6) vkQueueWaitIdle(presentQueue)

I got to 3a, and then I got an error in the validation layer saying that the image was not created with VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT usage flag.  How do I cause the swapchain images to be created with this usage bit?

Please let me know if additional information is needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vulkan part is pretty self explanatory; there's a `imageUsage` member. Let me just give you code:

```
VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR caps;
errco = vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR( pdev, mySurface, &caps ); if(errco) panic();
if( !(caps.supportedUsageFlags & VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT) ) panic();

VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR sci = {VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_INFO_KHR};
sci.surface = mySurface;
sci.imageUsage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT; // !
// etc

VkSwapchainKHR mySwapchain;
errco = vkCreateSwapchainKHR( dev, &sci, nullptr, &mySwapchain ); if(errco) panic();
```

Though you should probably not be doing it anyway. There is no reason to do `vkCmdClearColorImage`. Use render pass to clear color images before you intend to write them (`VkAttachmentDescription::loadOp`). It is more efficient and as a bonus it counts as a render and does not need `TRANSFER` usage.

It seems [windowBackgroundFallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowBackgroundFallback) is supposed to be the general solution to this assuming your app cannot provide a new image in time.

The best solution to get rid of the phantom image is to tell android not to shutdown the app if a screen resize occurs. This way, the screen resize can be handled by recreating the swapchain and redrawing the game.  This [article](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) talks setting [android:configChanges](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) in the manifests file.  The following setting stops android from shutting down the app when a screen resize from split screen to full screen occurs:

`android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|screenLayout"`

Comment: So, I tested out the windowBackgroundFallback solution and have no luck there.  I set this attribute in my SurfaceView in the xml file:

android:windowBackgroundFallback="@drawable/empty_background"

then I created a drawable like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
    android:color="#00000000" />
    <size
        android:width="500dp"
        android:height="500dp"/>
</shape>`

It still has the phantom images

Comment: I tested out the vulkan code you gave me (thank you!) and it worked. The phantom image after resize is gone. But, as you pointed out, it is a bad solution. I shouldn't need to request a feature that only gets used when the app is getting resized. I also tried doing a render pass with no draw commands in it.  This also worked (with no complaints from the validation layer).  No more phantom image.  It still seems a little kludgy.  Is there anything else I should do to the surface before the render thread shuts down?

Comment: Well I think best solution would be to instruct Android not to tear down the whole thing and instead just handle the resize\reconfigure event. Other than that, rather than clearing the old swapchain color, simply new swapchain should be created  and an actual usable image should be rendered asap.

Comment: actually, that is not possible.  Android calls SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceDestroyed (in Java).  I implemented this callback and use it to tell the render thread to stop.  The android documentation states that after this callback function is called by the system, the surface should not be accessed again. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html?hl=en#surfaceDestroyed(android.view.SurfaceHolder) I do recreate the swapchain if the surface is resized in such a way that does not cause the surface to be destroyed.

Comment: @CeruleanQuasar I know Android less than I would wish, but wouldn't setting appropriate [`android:configChanges`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) prevent the destruction of the surface?

Comment: [This](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window) says: "As discussed in Handling Configuration Changes, your activity **can handle the configuration change itself**, or it can allow the system to destroy the activity and recreate it with the new dimensions."

Comment: I tested this suggestion and it works.  The surface no longer gets torn down and rebuilt.  This fixes the problem of the phantom image.  I think making the changes to android:configChanges is the best solution.

Comment: @CeruleanQuasar I am not sure what the exact values to be used are. Would you mind editing the answer with the info about the exact use of `android:configChanges`?